# What anime is this image of a girl caressing a skeleton from?

Tags: dusk-maiden-of-amnesia

I found this picture on a fansub website, and it did not have any reference to the name of the anime to which it belongs.

[image: Image of girl caressing a skeleton]

Does anyone know where it is from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The image is related to the anime [**Dusk Maiden of Amnesia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dusk_Maiden_of_Amnesia) (or *Tasogare Otome x Amnesia*), which aired in 2012 and had a manga running from 2009-2013. The character in it, Kanoe Yuuko, is a ghost haunting an old school, who can only be seen by a few other people, namely Niiya Teiichi and Kanoe Kirie.

Here's wikipedia's plot summary:

> The story revolves around a first-year middle school student, Teiichi Niiya who had just enrolled at Seikyou Private Academy. When he gets lost in one of the school's old buildings, he meets a girl named Yuko Kanoe who reveals herself as a ghost with no memories. Teiichi then decides to investigate her death by looking through the school's seven mysteries revolving around her. Throughout the story, Teiichi and Yuko discover the truth about these ghost stories and help those who are troubled.

The image seems to be an edited version of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmT3t.jpg), which (as best I can tell) is official promo art. This image has also been used for a [wall scroll](http://www.amiami.com/top/detail/detail?gcode=CGD2-31144). A [rotated and cropped version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRSYs.jpg) was used as the album cover for the single Choir Jail, the OP of the anime.